# Zend Framework 2 match current url to route

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2, zend-route

I'm trying to match the current url a user is on to a route, and output an 'active' class if the route matches:

```
<?php if($this->url() == $this->url('dashboard')) echo "class='active'" ?>
```

This works on routes that exist. However, this will mess up 404 routing; if I go to a route that doesn't exist, i.e. localhost/someurl, I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'No RouteMatch instance provided'
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: with a 404 routemath is not set. What about catching the exception ?

Answer (score 0):

You try:

Controller:

```
public function dashboardAction(){
    return new ViewModel(array(
            'dashboard' => true,
    ));
}
```

View:

```
<div class="<?php echo $this->dashboard ? 'active' : ''?> other-class">Dashboard</div>
```

Good luck. :D

Comment: This works for the dashboard view, but I'm rendering my navigation outside of the dashboard view..

Comment: You try: $this->layout()->setTemplate('tpl-path/tpl-name', array('dashboard' => true));

[Navigation](https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.navigation.quick-start.html)